# A way for dynamically allocated objects to be automatically deleted after a set period of time

Tags: c++

I'm looking for suggestions for ways of having all objects of a particular class I'm dealing with (lets call it class A) to automatically "self-destruct" after a fixed period of time. For the sake of argument let's say after exactly 3 days.

- It is guaranteed that all objects of
  class A will only ever be created on
  the heap.
- It is also guaranteed that no object
  of class A will ever be accessed 72
  hours after it was created (so
  deleting the object after 3 days is
  entirely safe).

[These objects will be accessed by client code potentially multiple times for up to 72 hours. While the client code can indeed invoke a destroy() method on each object of class A when it knows its done using it, I don't want to rely on the client cleaning up these objects. To avoid possible memory leaks, I want to ensure they are cleaned up without client intervention, i.e. for them to self-destruct after 72 hours.]

What are the recommended ways of doing this, to create-and-forget?

Comment: This question is insane, but great.

Answer (score 3):

One approach is to have a "registry" for all those objects and something that would periodically check that "registry" and delete too old objects. That could be a timer procedure or a separate thread or some routine periodically run from the client code. When you add an object address to the registry you store the time of adding along with the address. Of course those objects will need some common base to allow polymorphic destruction and deallocation.

Answer (score 3):

You should really use [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) for resource managment in C++. In your case, using a [`boost::shared_ptr`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm) could solve your problem.

Comment: Theoretically a `shared_ptr` is also good but it will delete your objects as soon as they are no more referenced, not after some time. Maybe some object will still hold a reference but never use it anymore. So +1 for the idea but it does not answer this precise question.

Comment: @Benoit: Might be, just wanted to point out all options. Also, I would consider an object holding a reference it is sure to never use again a design flaw.

Comment: @Space_C0wb0y: you are totally right to point to this option because odds are OP will have a use for it and take your solution.

Comment: +1 The other answers tackle the question, but this answer tackles the root of the problem!

Comment: Thanks but a shared_ptr won't cut it here, for the exact reason Benoit pointed out above; it won't delete my objects after a given period of time.

Comment: @arjunaw: The argument is that the design to delete objects after a certain time probably flawed. If a client is sure to never use an object again, it should not keep the reference.

Comment: I understand what you're saying but the problem is that's just the way the client code is and unfortunately for me, I can't touch the client code. Using a shared_ptr or any other type of smart pointer is out of the question here.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to implement that they expire if they are not used for a period of time. This is common with client/server technology where you cache items that a client is using so they are readily available when they are requested, and it is a technique for connectionless servers where clients have a session that request objects and use them, so no it is not a crazy question, it has practical benefits.

I generally find that I would use LRU technique, (least recently used) and the best container for this is std::list. When an item is accessed you can "splice" your list to move the item to the front. Much of the time you deal with list-iterators, which remain valid even when moved around the list.

At various times you may do some "cleanup" on your list. You could have a process that checks over a period of time for expired items, or it might be event driven and know when the next expiry time is.

Of course if the client comes back and attempts to access the item you must be ready to recreate it in the state it was at the point of deletion.

Comment: Thanks, yes you have it spot on. It is to clean up CORBA NameIterators that the server creates and which the client uses over a period of time to retrieve names and when its done no longer has a need for the object. So I'm wondering what would be a good choice for a timer to use here? It needs to be thread-safe as my application is multi-threaded (pthreads, HPUX 11) and there'll be objects of my class A being created by multiple threads at any given time.

Comment: I'm a Windows developer, so not much help on what to use for a timer, but look at Intel's TBB `concurrent_queue` for storing pointers to the objects. You can then have a timer of some sort fire every N seconds, check the first item on the queue's creation time, delete it if it's too old, and so on.

Comment: A lot of this may involve designing the interface in such a way that the object doesn't have to be there on the server but must be available to be retrieved, and that the server may cache it for optimisation purpose. If you return an object over CORBA to the client I don't think you can just delete it.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can instantiate a `static std::list<Your_class *>` in your class. Every new instance of the class is pushed to the back of that list, and a timer calls regularly a function that pops and destroys items in the front of the list when they are too old.

Note that if you want to extend the lifespan of a particular instance in the middle of its life, then a list structure is probably not good because you will have to perform a linear scan…

In this case, you want a container in which you have quick insert and removes at both ends, and where you can find an element quickly, with quick deletions in the middle of it. I can only suggest also having a `static std::map<Your_class *, std::list<Your_class *>::iterator>` that allows you to quickly find elements in your list.

Otherwise read the answer about `shared_ptr`s. This is the best advice that can be provided to you. If nothing prevents you from using it, then switch to it and do not implement what I told you.

Comment: Thanks, yes that's an optional requirement at this stage, to have the timer reset so that the lifespan of the object can be extended. So I'm wondering what would be a good choice for a timer to use here? It needs to be thread-safe as my application is multi-threaded (pthreads, HPUX 11) and there'll be objects of my class A being created by multiple threads at any given time.

Comment: Sorry, I lost the window for editing my last reply above after you edited yours to include mentioning shared_ptrs. Since I can't use shared_ptrs (for reasons I won't go into here as it just complicates matters), I was wondering what would be a good choice for a timer to use here? It needs to be thread-safe as my application is multi-threaded (pthreads, HPUX 11) and there'll be objects of my class A being created by multiple threads at any given time.

Comment: @arjunaw: Then use mutexes during any operation to access objects of your class. Since your life span is 3 days, a timer of 10 minutes could be enough unless you want high precision. Then set it to 2 millisocends. !)

Answer (score 0):

i think if you had something like become and had the object become a none singleton that would reject the method calls on it the process of becoming none would be managed by a resource pool that would keep a reference to each object and the time it was created and when the object becomes older than 3 days it would have it become none

Answer (score 0):

I would implement some simple garbage-collector system and allocate your objects through it.

Assuming that the objects cannot cross-reference themselves, it should be fairly easy.

For example, the garbage-collector class could hold a double-ended queue (e.g. [`std::deque`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Deque.html)) containg object pointers and their creation time. When creating new objects, they would be put at the end of the queue. From time to time I would call a function `purge()` would be called which would check objects which are at the front of the queue (the oldest) and remove them when applicable.